# Compare subscriptions on Cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am trying to compare the predicate of an existing subscription the user has, with the one he is about to create. Just to make sure I do not create the same subscription twice.

But my `if subscription.predicate! == predicate always` returns `false`

My predicate:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate()
predicate = NSPredicate(format:"validUserIDs CONTAINS %@ AND expiryDate > %@ AND NOT(invalidUserIDs CONTAINS %@)", userCloudID!, dateNow, userCloudID!)
```

My fetch subscrition method

```
 publicDatabase.fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler { (subscriptions: [CKSubscription]?, error: NSError?) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - fetch subscription error")
        }
        else
        {
            print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - fetch subscription no error")
            if subscriptions?.count == 0
            {
                print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription count = 0, create")
                subscribe()
            }
            else
            {
                print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription count > 0, create")
                var exists = false
                for subscription in subscriptions!
                {
                    if subscription.predicate == predicate
                    {
                        print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription count > 0, true")
                        exists = true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription count > 0, false")
                        exists = false
                    }
                }
                if exists == false
                {
                    print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription do not exists, create")
                    subscribe()
                }
                else
                {
                    print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription already exists")
                    result(error: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could find an answer for my issue. Basically comparing the `alertBoddies` it found in the query with the `alertBody` it intends to create.

```
if subscriptionUpdate.notificationInfo!.alertBody == subscription.notificationInfo!.alertBody
```

**Should look like this:**

```
publicDatabase.fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler { (subscriptions: [CKSubscription]?, error: NSError?) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - fetch subscription error")
        }
        else
        {
            print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - fetch subscription no error")
            if subscriptions?.count == 0
            {
                print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription count = 0, create")
                subscribe()
            }
            else
            {
                print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription count > 0, create")
                var exists = false
                for subscription in subscriptions!
                {
                     print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription compare, \(subscriptionUpdate.notificationInfo!.alertBody) = \(subscription.notificationInfo!.alertBody)")
                    if subscriptionUpdate.notificationInfo!.alertBody == subscription.notificationInfo!.alertBody
                    {
                        print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription count > 0, exists = true")
                        exists = true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription count > 0, exists = false")
                    }
                }
                if exists == false
                {
                    print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription do not exists, create")
                    subscribe()
                }
                else
                {
                    print("-> cloudKitSubscribeToChat - subscription already exists")
                    result(error: nil)
                }
            }
        }
```